# how to combine regEx expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I take each of these and combine them into a single regEx expression?

```
var t = "<test>";
t = t.replace(/^</, '');
t = t.replace(/>+$/, '');
```

which results in t equal to test without the <>

Comment: Use the "or" operator  `|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipe `|`. In regex it means OR:

```
t = "<test>>".replace(/^<|>+$/g, "");
// "test"
```

But of course, you can use another ways like:

```
t = "<test>>".replace(/[<>]/g, "");
// "test"
```

or even with match:

```
t = "<test>>".match(/\w+/)[0];
// "test"
```

Make sure you've added the `g`-global flag when needed. This flag stands for *all occurrences*.

Comment: the first one is what I was looking for and I had tried it but did not have the global flag hence it only replaced the first <

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you only want to replace beginning '<' symbols and ending '>' symbols, try this one `[>$^<]`

```
var t = "<test>";
t = t.replace('/[>$^<]/', '');
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  First off it is not a regular expression so it is going to look to replace the string literal '[>$^<]' with ''.  Secondly if I make is a regular expression it only replace the < not the >

Comment: Actually this will work if you add the g for the global flag... t=t.replace(/[>$^<]/g,'');

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I used quotes instead of slash, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
t = t.replace(/^</, '').replace(/>+$/, '');
```

If you want it in single line, use | to combine the regex.. Like this

```
t = t.replace(/^<|>+$/g, "");
```

or capture groups like this

```
t = t.replace(/^<(.*)>+$/g, '$1');
```